# How can I create a filter that formats an HTML tag around each element in a generated array?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array that holds the values that the user inputs. The number of inputs and therefore the number of elements is based on a button click like so:

```
<input type="text" id="genTxt" placeholder="Enter an item" ng-model="genExpr.genArrays[$index]" ng-repeat="genArray in genExpr.genArrays track by $index">
<button ng-click="addTxtField()">Add item</button>
<button ng-click="removeTxtField()">Remove item</button>
```

With the related Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("outputApp", []);

app.controller("outputCtrl", function($scope) {

$scope.genExpr = { genArrays: [] };

$scope.addTxtField = function() {
$scope.genExpr.genArrays.push('');
}

$scope.removeTxtField = function() {
$scope.genExpr.genArrays.pop('');
} 

});
```

What I need is a filter that is able to wrap each element in genArrays with an html tag, such as <li></li>. So far the closest I've gotten is the following.

```
app.filter('liTag', function () {
return function (items) {
            return "<li>" + items + "</li>"
};
});
```

Which creates the tags even if the array is empty and around the entire array as well.

```
<ul><li>test,test,test,test</li></ul>
```

The goal, rather, would be this.

```
<ul><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li></ul>
```

My other attempts have failed, including one where the filter had a conditional and returned "" if the array is empty.

I have the whole of it in plunker for easier viewing.

https://plnkr.co/edit/8FVrcOwOgr1wze4By4Hz?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simply loop through the individual elements in the array and add the `li` tags like so.

```js
var app = angular.module("outputApp", []);

app.controller("outputCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.genExpr = {
    genArrays: []
  };

  $scope.addTxtField = function() {
    $scope.genExpr.genArrays.push('');
  }

  $scope.removeTxtField = function() {
    $scope.genExpr.genArrays.pop('');
  }

});

app.filter('liTag', function() {
  return function(items) {
    var result = ""
    for (var item of items) {
      result += "<li>" + item + "</li>";
    }
    return result
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="outputApp" ng-controller="outputCtrl">

  <input type="text" id="genTxt" placeholder="Enter an item" ng-model="genExpr.genArrays[$index]" ng-repeat="genArray in genExpr.genArrays track by $index">
  <button ng-click="addTxtField()">Add item</button><button ng-click="removeTxtField()">Remove item</button>

  <textarea id="output">&lt;ul>{{ genExpr.genArrays | liTag }}&lt;/ul></textarea>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the quick and successful response.